# Modifying population mortality/morbidity tables for sub-population experience

Tags: r, bayesian, survival-analysis, population

I have a population morbidity table that shows proportion of people expected to become sick by age, gender, smoker-status etc. Let's call this population-P1.

I also have sample data of sickness incidence from a sub-population of population-P1. Let's call this population-P2.

It is not known if population-P2 has the same or different morbidity as population-P1.

Is there an R package (or package in an alternative language) that modifies the morbidity table associated with population-P1 in light of the data from population-P2 to give a morbidity table for population-P2?

I haven't been able to find something on CRAN. I'm hoping the collective knowledge in this forum can help signpost me. Thank you in advance.